# Ionic scrollTop "Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of null" (still exists in 1.0.0-rc.1)

Tags: ionic-framework

This bug was referred to here: [in ionic changing route causes "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414381/in-ionic-changing-route-causes-typeerror-cannot-read-property-scrollto-of-nu)

The answer says that this bug was fixed in beta-13, but I'm using 1.0.0-rc.1 and the bug still appears.

In my case, it the error is showing when navigating back to a page that uses `$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop()`

Is anyone else getting this error after updating to rc.1?

EDIT:
I find that if I do not call `$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop()` automatically when my view loads, the error does not come up. Should I be calling `scrollTop()` within a specific Ionic event that waits for the right time?

Comment: I just upgraded from rc.0 to rc.2 and I suddenly have this error. However, I don't believe I'm even using any of Ionic's scroll methods...

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem, even with v1.0.0 "uranium-unicorn".

Wrapping the scroll call into a $timeout helped - this is what it looks like in my code:

```
   $timeout(function() {
                $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(scrollPosition.left, scrollPosition.top);
            }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put it in

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Im late to this but was getting the same error but by calling the scroll top element with:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
```

but rather:

```
var scrollTop = e.detail.scrollTop;
```

and fixed my by using the following:

`var scrollTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top;`

Im also using js scrolling as it seems to work better with the scrolla-sista plugin so I have the following in my `config` block at the start of my app

```
  $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(true);
```

where their [docs state](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/):

```
Whether to use JS or Native scrolling. Defaults to native scrolling. Setting this to true has the same effect as setting each ion-content to have overflow-scroll='false'.
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I saw this solution on this thread [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-beta-12-strange-error/9801/16) and it worked for me with version 1.0.0-beta.14

If upgrading to version 1.0.0-beta.14 is not an option, you can change the ionic-bundle.js file with the following:

Approximately Line 39910:

```
this.scrollTop = function(shouldAnimate) {
  this.resize().then(function() {
    if(typeof scrollView !== 'undefined' && scrollView !== null){
     scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0, !!shouldAnimate);
    }
  });
};
```

And Approximately line 39813:

```
if (!angular.isDefined(scrollViewOptions.bouncing)) {
  ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    if(!scrollView){
      return;
    }
    scrollView.options.bouncing = true;

    if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
      // No bouncing by default on Android
      scrollView.options.bouncing = false;
      // Faster scroll decel
      scrollView.options.deceleration = 0.95;
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

> e.detail.scrollTop

to

> e.target.scrollTop

then this will Work